# postfix and external smtp server - lost connection while sending MAIL FROM

Tags: email, smtp

i'm trying to configure postfix to work with an external smtp server.
This is my main.cf file (this is from a fresh installation and few customize settings):

```
#myorigin = /etc/mailname

smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no

# appending .domain is the MUA's job.
append_dot_mydomain = no

# Uncomment the next line to generate "delayed mail" warnings
#delay_warning_time = 4h

readme_directory = no

# TLS parameters
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache

# See /usr/share/doc/postfix/TLS_README.gz in the postfix-doc package for
# information on enabling SSL in the smtp client.

smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated                     defer_unauth_destination
myhostname = ubuntuTesting
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = ubuntuTesting, localhost.localdomain, localhost
relayhost = smtp.site.it
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = +
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = all

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_path = smtpd
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_sasl_type = cyrus
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes

# optional: necessary if email provider uses load balancing and
# forwards emails to another smtp server
# for delivery (ie: smtp.yahoo.com --&gt; smtp.phx.1.yahoo.com)
smtp_cname_overrides_servername = no
```

I've created the sasl_passwd with smtp, username and password. When i try to send an email with 'mail' command this is the output in the logs

```
Jun 12 15:13:13 ubuntuTesting postfix/qmgr[2390]: AE6FD1E136B: from=<ubuntu@ubuntuTesting>, size=368, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jun 12 15:13:14 ubuntuTesting postfix/smtp[2401]: AE6FD1E136B: enabling PIX workarounds: disable_esmtp delay_dotcrlf for smtp.site.com[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:25
Jun 12 15:13:14 ubuntuTesting postfix/smtp[2401]: AE6FD1E136B: to=<stefano@site.com>, relay=smtp.site.com[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:25, delay=0.72, delays=0.04/0.04/0.59/0.05, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with smtp.site.com[xxx.xxx.xx.xx] while sending MAIL FROM)
Jun 12 15:23:03 ubuntuTesting postfix/smtp[2491]: AE6FD1E136B: enabling PIX workarounds: disable_esmtp delay_dotcrlf for smtp.site.com[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:25
Jun 12 15:23:03 ubuntuTesting postfix/smtp[2491]: AE6FD1E136B: to=<stefano@site.com>, relay=smtp.site.com[xxx.xxx.xx.xx]:25, delay=590, delays=589/0.01/0.36/0.04, dsn=4.4.2, status=deferred (lost connection with smtp.site.com[xxx.xxx.xx.xx] while sending MAIL FROM)
```

I think the issues is that the smtp server accept AUTH PLAIN login type, but i can't figure out how to login correctly. I've tried a lot of things.

I can make it works with my google account, but not with this one.